# Packer build amazon-ebs: sudo: puppet: command not found

Tags: puppet, packer

While packer build, I get this error for puppet call:

```
==> amazon-ebs: Provisioning with Puppet...
    amazon-ebs: Creating Puppet staging directory...
    amazon-ebs: Creating directory: /tmp/packer-puppet-masterless
    amazon-ebs: Uploading manifests...
    amazon-ebs: Creating directory: /tmp/packer-puppet-masterless/manifests
    amazon-ebs: Uploading manifest file from: file.pp
    amazon-ebs: Running Puppet: cd /tmp/packer-puppet-masterless && FACTER_packer_build_name='amazon-ebs' FACTER_packer_builder_type='amazon-ebs' sudo -E puppet apply --detailed-exitcodes /tmp/packer-puppet-masterless/manifests/file.pp
==> amazon-ebs: sudo: puppet: command not found
==> amazon-ebs: Prvisioning step had errors: Running the cleanup provisioner, if present...
```

My environment is: $ packer -version 1.7.2

```
Packer Template : 
{
    "builders": [
        {
            "ami_name": "packer-linux-aws-demo-{{timestamp}}",
            "instance_type": "t3.micro",
            "region": "us-west-2",
            "source_ami_filter": {
            "filters": {
            "virtualization-type": "hvm",
            "name": "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*",
            "root-device-type": "ebs"
            },
            "most_recent": true
            },
            "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
            "type": "amazon-ebs"
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
        
        {
            "type": "puppet-masterless",
            "manifest_file": "file.pp"
        }
    ]
}

=========
file.pp
$ cat file.pp
file { "/var/tmp/testfile":
        ensure => "present",
        owner => "root",
        group => "root",
        mode => "664",
        content => "This is a test file created using puppet.
                    Puppet is really cool",
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a path problem? Where is `puppet` on your node?

Comment: The Packer `puppet-masterless` provisioner does not install Puppet on the image. You either need Puppet installed on the base image, or to bootstrap Puppet prior to provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

Like Matt's comment says, Puppet won't be installed on the image for you, you need to do that yourself. If you're using Ubuntu you can use the inline-shell provisioner to do something like

```
"provisioners": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "inline": [
            "apt-get update",
            "apt-get install puppet -y",
    }, {
```

In my case the Puppet binary wasn't on my path (since my builder type is docker), but you can use the *puppet_bin_dir* attribute of the pupet-masterless provisioner to specify it's location

```
    }, {
        "type": "puppet-masterless",
        "manifest_file": "site.pp",
        "puppet_bin_dir": "/opt/puppetlabs/bin"
    }
]
```